# import glob.glob unable to import

Tags: python, import, module, package, anaconda

When I try to either `import glob` or `from glob import glob`, it works just fine, but when I try `import glob.glob`, it gives the error as below :

```
No module named 'glob.glob'; 'glob' is not a package
```

Is glob not a sub module within glob module ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case in default installation of Python 2.7 same situation, probably is correct and normal behavior. (checked on windows and linux python)